# tikz, pgfplots and polaraxis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

I found a nice template for a polar graph [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdReQ.png) and I adjusted it as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\huge
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \edef\val{0}
    \foreach \a in {0, 1,...,359}
    \draw[Azure4] (\a:9.7) -- (\a:10);
    \foreach \a in {0, 5,...,359}
    \draw[Azure4] (\a:9.5) -- (\a:10);          
    \foreach \r in {5,6,...,9}
    \draw[black!45] (0,0) circle (\r);    
    \draw[black, ultra thick] (0,0) circle (10);    
    \foreach \r in {5, 6,...,10}
      {
      \draw (\r,0) node[inner sep=1pt,below=3pt,rectangle,fill=white] {$\val$};
      \pgfmathparse{int(\val+1)}
      \xdef\val{\pgfmathresult}
      }
    \draw (7.5,0) node[inner sep=1pt,above=3pt,rectangle,fill=white] {wear (mm)};
    \foreach \a in {0, 90,...,359}
    \draw[very thick] (\a:5) -- (\a:10);
    \draw (0: 10.5) node {$0$};
    \draw (90: 10.5) node {$\pi/2$};
    \draw (180: 10.5) node {$\pi$};
    \draw (270: 10.5) node {$3\pi/2$};
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle(1.1mm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From this blank graph I would like to add some data that I read from an external text file, say `data.txt`.

So far, the only way I found to include external data is related to the `\addplot` command and I am thus thinking to use the `polaraxis` environment.

The file `data.txt` contains two columns, for example:

```
t   u
0   1
20  2
40  3
60  4
100 5
130 4
160 3
180 2
220 2
240 3
260 3
290 3
300 1
320 1
360 1
360 10
360 1
```

First, in order to read data I am using:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\data
```

then within the tikzpicture I create my polar axis environment:

```
\begin{polaraxis}[%
xmin=0, xmax=360,
xtick={},
xticklabels={},
xticklabels={},
xlabel={},
ylabel={},
yticklabels={},
axis lines = none,
filter discard warning=false,
axis on top]
\addplot [color=blue,each nth point=1,very thick] table [x=t,y=u] {\data};
\end{polaraxis}
```

I obtain this graph in the end:

[image]

My questions are : (1) how can I have the same origin for both `polaraxis` and my tikzpicture and (2) can I read my data directly using a `\draw` command without using `polaraxis` and `\addplot`?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdReQ.png) http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/polar-coordinates-template/

Comment: You can extract the entries of a \pgfplotstable one at a time using \pgfplotstablegetelem in a \foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them should be inside the *same* `tikzpicture` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotstableread{
t   u
0   1
20  2
40  3
60  4
100 5
130 4
160 3
180 2
220 2
240 3
260 3
290 3
300 1
320 1
360 1
360 10
360 1
}{\data}

\tikzset{mypic/.pic={%
    \begin{scope}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
    \edef\val{#1}
    \foreach \a in {0, 1,...,359}
    \draw[Azure4] (\a:9.7) -- (\a:10);
    \foreach \a in {0, 5,...,359}
    \draw[Azure4] (\a:9.5) -- (\a:10);
    \foreach \r in {5,6,...,9}{
    \draw[black!45] (0,0) circle (\r);
    }
    \draw[black, ultra thick] (0,0) circle (10);
    \foreach \r in {5, 6,...,10}
      {
      \draw (\r,0) node[inner sep=1pt,below=3pt,rectangle,fill=white] {$\val$};
      \pgfmathparse{int(\val+1)}
      \xdef\val{\pgfmathresult}
      }
    \draw (7.5,0) node[inner sep=1pt,above=3pt,rectangle,fill=white] {wear (mm)};
    \foreach \a in {0, 90,...,359}{
    \draw[very thick] (\a:5) -- (\a:10);
    }
    \draw (0: 10.5) node {$0$};
    \draw (90: 10.5) node {$\pi/2$};
    \draw (180: 10.5) node {$\pi$};
    \draw (270: 10.5) node {$3\pi/2$};
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle(1.1mm);
     \end{scope}
  }
}


\begin{document}
\huge

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{polaraxis}[%
xmin=0, xmax=360,clip=false,
xtick={},
xticklabels={},
xticklabels={},
xlabel={},
ylabel={},
yticklabels={},
axis lines = none,
filter discard warning=false,
axis on top]
\addplot [color=blue,each nth point=1,very thick] table [x=t,y=u] {\data};
\pic {mypic={0}};

\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is great, so basically you created a background for the polaraxis environment if I get it correctly. Thanks !

Comment: @Alain It is not the background but I have drawn them one top of another using the `pic` facility.